# How do I apply gsub subject to a function?

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

I"m using Rails 5 and Ruby 2.4.  I have a function

```
my_function(str1, str2)
```

that will return true or false given two string arguments.  What I would like to do is given a larger string, for instance

```
"a   b   c d"
```

I would like to replace two consecutive "words" (a word by my definition is a sequence of characters followed by a word boundary) with the empty string if the expression

```
my_function(str1, str2)
```

evaluates to true for those two consecutive words.  So for instance, if

```
my_function("b", "c")
```

evaluates to true, I would like the above string to become

```
"a    d"
```

How do I do this?

**Edit:** I'm including the output based on Tom Lord's answer ...

If I use

```
  def stuff(line)
    matches = line.scan(/\b((\S+?)\b.*?\b(\S+?))\b/)
    matches.each do |full_match, word1, word2|
      line.delete!(full_match) if word1.eql?("hello") && word2.eql?("world") 
    end
  end
```

and line is

```
"hello world this is a test"
```

the resulting string line is

```
"tisisatst"
```

THis is not quite what I expected.  THe result should be

```
" this is a test"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** This is an updated answer, based on the comments below. I have left my original answer at the bottom.

Scanning a string for "two consecutive words" is a bit tricky. Your best option is probably to use the `\b` anchor in a regex, which signifies a "word boundary":

```
string_to_change = "a   b   c d"

matches = string_to_change.scan(/\b((\S+?)\b.*?\b(\S+?))\b/)
  # => [["a   b", "a", "b"], ["c d", "c", "d"]]
```

...Where the first string is the "full match" (including any whitespace or punctuation), the others are the two words.

To break down that regex:

- `\b` means "word boundary". I have placed one of each side of both strings. *This solution assumes that `str1` and `str2` are both a single word*. (If they contain spaces, then I don't know what behaviour you expect?)
- `\S+?` means "one or more non-whitespace character". (Matching non-greedily, so it will stop matching at the **first** word boundary).

You can then remove each "full match" from the string, if the method returns true for the two words:

```
matches.each do |full_match, word1, word2|
  string_to_change.gsub!(full_match, '') if my_function(word1, word2)
end
```

One thing that's *not accounted for* here (you didn't specify this well in your question...) was how to handle strings containing three or more words. For example, consider the following:

```
"hello world this is a test"
```

Suppose `my_function(word1, word2)` returns `true` only for the pairs: `"world", "this"` and `"hello", "is"`.

My code above will *only* look at the pairs: `"hello", "world"`, `"this", "is"` and `"a", "test"`. But perhaps it should actually:

1. Look at *all* pairs of words, i.e. match all words with the left- and right- hand side.
2. Delete pairs of words **repeatedly**, i.e. after the initial pair: `"world this"` is removed, the string should be re-scanned and then `"hello is"` should also be removed?

If such further enhancements are needed, then please explain them clearly in a new question (if you are struggling to solve the problem yourself).

---

**Original answer:**

```
str1 = "b"
str2 = "c"
string_to_change = "a   b   c d"

if my_function(str1, str2)
  string_to_change.gsub!(/\b#{str1}\b\s+\b#{str2}\b/, "")
end
```

To break down that regex:

- `\b` means "word boundary". I have placed one of each side of both strings. *This solution assumes that `str1` and `str2` are both a single word*. (If they contain spaces, then I don't know what behaviour you expect?)
- `\s+` means "one or more whitespace character". You may wish to tweak this to allow other punctuation too, such as a comma or full stop. A fully generic solution to this issue could in fact be:

.

```
string_to_change.gsub!(/\b#{str1}\b.(\B.)*#{str2}\b/, "")

# Or equivalently:

string_to_change.gsub!(/\b#{str1}\b(.\B)*.#{str2}\b/, "")
```

`.(\B.)*` is instead collecting each character, one at a time, always checking that it's not the first letter of a word (i.e. is proceeded by a non-word boundary).

Comment: It's an `if` statement, not a method. Yes, you can.

Comment: (So long as you first define the `my_function` method, and make it return `true`) try running this in a console. It works fine.

Comment: Thanks but you have hard-coded several things in your solution.  I was just listing "b" and "c" as an example.  There are a number of parametesr that can cause my_function(str1, str2) to be true.  What if I'm just given a long string of text?  How do I make the logic work then?

Comment: @Dave Sorry, I don't understand... You obviously wouldn't hardcode those strings in your application; you'd make it into a method that accepts parameters. I only gave hardcoded values so that the code sample is complete.

Comment: Hi @Tom, if "strip_from_string" only contains a "string_to_change" parameter, what goes in the "...." block?  That is essentially what my question is.

Comment: The `....` block is what I wrote in my answer!! Based on your question, I presumed that `string_to_change`, `str1` and `str2` were three variables you are given. Are you instead, actually, saying that you need to scan for all consecutive words in the string and only then remove them if `my_function(word1, word2)` returns true?

Comment: Yes you have summarized it correctly -- I'm sayihng that I need to scan for all consecutive words in the string and only then remove them if my_function(word1, word2) returns true.

Comment: OK, can you please edit your question to explain this clearly. I will update my answer too.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your expanded answer.  I included the output of waht I get from yoru question.  I used a very simple "My_function", whcih was 'word1.eql?("hello") && word2.eql?("world")'.  However, the resulting string is getting a bit mangled.  Hopefully I'm applyihng your logic properly.  Let me know if I'm not.

Comment: Oh... Yeah, sorry, you need to use `gsub!(full_match, '')`, not `delete!(full_match)`. My bad. [`String#delete!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-delete) will delete *all supplied characters*, not just an exact string match.

Comment: I would highly advise you to try experimenting with things like this yourself! Learning to program is not just about copy+pasting answers from StackOverflow ;)

Comment: Really appreciate your suggestions here.  Tried replacing "delete!" with "gsub!" but now nothing happens (nothign is replaced).

Comment: Did you add the second parameter of an empty string? It works fine for me.